# Why is Pandas replace() method not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am trying to replace all columns in my df with prices to ints however for some reason the replace() method isn't working:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f_name, dtype="string")
df = df[df.columns.dropna()]
df[cols_int] = df[cols_int].replace({"[\$]": "", "[,]": ""}, regex=True)
df[cols_int] = df[cols_int].astype(int)
```

Error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$499,000'
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: you need to use the replace for the string represenation of the series: `df[cols_int].str.replace({"[\$]": "", "[,]": ""}, regex=True)` -> place `.str.`in between.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this works on multiple columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is  bug with `dtype='string'`: [pandas-dev/pandas #35977 - BUG: replacement works for object but not string dtype](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/35977)

It should work as expected if you load with `dtype=str` or `dtype='str'`:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(f_name, dtype=str)
df = df[df.columns.dropna()]
df[cols_int] = df[cols_int].replace({"[\$]": "", "[,]": ""}, regex=True)
df[cols_int] = df[cols_int].astype(int)
```